# Interaction between 2 smart contracts?

Tags: contract-design, tokens

I will make an example of what kind of interaction i'm asking for:

- Sender send X quantity of token A to smart contract 1
- Smart contract 1 elaborate the information and send it to smart contract 2
- Smart contract 2 send the right quantity of token B to the original sender

is it possible to make this kind of interactions? thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because sending tokens is a different use case compared to executing functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Detecting the transfer of token A to contract 1

What you ask is possible, but the difficulty lies in detecting that contract A has transferred it's tokens to contract 1.

There are several possibilities depending upon the capabilities of contract A.

### The easy way

If A is an ERC223 contract, then it's really easy.

Simply implement the `tokenFallback` function in your contract 1 and when you get the callback, verify the `msg.sender` is contract A, then call contract 2 to transfer the required amount of B tokens to the `from` address.

#### Example:

```
function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) external {
    require(msg.sender == a_token);
    b_token.transfer(_from, _value);
}
```

### The hard way

Sometimes life is not easy.

In this case you may have to get the holder of token A to `approve` contract 1 to transfer tokens on their behalf, then call contract 1, which will transfer the A token and issue the B tokens.

#### Example:

```
function crossTransfer(uint _value) external {
    // This requires the sender has previously approved this transfer.
    a_token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, _value);
    b_token.transfer(_from, _value);
}
```

### Another possibility:

If you control all the contracts, a possibility may be to use something similar to this:

[Three token transfer between each other](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44351/three-tokens-transfer-between-each-other/44354#44354)

Comment: ok so it's possible to do it, that's a key point for me thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make smart contracts interact with each other but sending tokens is a different thing because you are interacting with the smart contract token, not with the token that you need.

Let's say you have this situation

- smart contract token ==> A
- smart contract 1 ==> B
- smart contract 2 ==> C

B sends token to C effectively means that B calls a function of A. And there will be no code that runs from C